# Querying multiple columns containing the same text, without using raw query methods

Tags: java, ormlite, query-builder

I need to search multiple columns in a table for the same value; ie. find all rows that have Acme in either company name, name, or email column.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to search multiple columns in a table for the same value. IE find all rows that have Acme in either company name, name or email column.

Sure.  You can use `QueryBuilder` to use the same text to query multiple fields.  Maybe something like:

```
QueryBuilder<Foo, Long> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
Where<Foo, Long> where = qb.where();
String name = "acme";
where.like(Foo.FIELD_COMPANY, "%" + name + "%");
where.or();
where.like(Foo.FIELD_NAME, "%" + name + "%");
where.or();
where.like(Foo.FIELD_EMAIL, "%" + name + "%");
List<Foo> results = where.list();
```

Here are more [docs about the query-builder](http://ormlite.com/docs/query-builder).